# IE11 Error: Unable to get property 'insertBefore' of undefined or null reference

Tags: jquery

I have an issue with JQUery  (all versions)
when trying to drag selectable on some cases I get:

```
IE11 Error: Unable to get property 'insertBefore' of undefined or null reference
```

See reproduce on the jsfiddle link below - if I select bottom 2 elements (drag to select) then drag them out - IE will throw undefined or null 
[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/sowL9m8w/